# Laravel 5.4, how do I find LoginController@showLoginForm?

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

in php artisan route:list I have

```
GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest
```

but when I go to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php all I have is the following. How do I find the '@showLoginForm' portion so I can edit this controller?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Comment: \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **LoginController**, you can see the following code:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Above line indicates that this class/controller (**LoginController**) is using **AuthenticatesUsers** Trait. And path of this trait is **\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php**

In this trait file, first function is **showLoginForm()**.

Comment: I see, I was too noob to know that, yay, now I know :)

Comment: @SimonSuh, Please accept my answer if it was helpful :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can see

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

`AuthenticateUsers` is a Trait in Laravel which resides in `/path/to/root/vendor/laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth`.

Traits in PHP is nothing but similar to interfaces, you can override the same method or variables where you include it or the same methods are variables in trait will take control.

if you want to override the method  for some additional functionality just write a method with same method name inside `LoginController` and implement your own logic. so the later one will work.

Comment: @simon suh, here I have mentioned what is Trait and why we are using trait